# Cannot find symbol @NonNull when adding Pushe plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pushe

I want to install [Pushe plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pushe) for flutter, but I'm having this error:

I even add this line to the native imports:

`import android.support.annotation.NonNull;`

but get the same exception.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PushePlugin.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PushePlugin
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PushePlugin.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PushePlugin
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PusheApplication.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            public void onNotificationReceived(@NonNull final NotificationData notificationData) {
                                                ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PusheApplication.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            public void onNotificationClicked(@NonNull final NotificationData notificationData) {
                                               ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PusheApplication.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
            public void onNotificationButtonClicked(@NonNull final NotificationData notificationData,
                                                     ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PusheApplication.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                                                    @NonNull final NotificationButtonData notificationButtonData) {
                                                     ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PusheApplication.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            public void onCustomContentReceived(@NonNull final JSONObject jsonObject) {
                                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\pushe-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\co\ronash\pushe\flutter\PusheApplication.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
            public void onNotificationDismissed(@NonNull final NotificationData notificationData) {
                                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pushe:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: You can resolve this using Android Studio. Open your android folder(Android Project in Android Studio)  then open PusheApplication class and import the package for @NunNull

Comment: @KailashChouhan >> i add this line : import android.support.annotation.NonNull; but have the same erroe, what is the package for NunNull ??

Comment: if you have migrated to androidX then try this import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to **[Pushe's Github repo](https://github.com/pusheco/pushe-flutter/releases)**, this issue's been fixed as of `version 1.0.1`.

> https://github.com/pusheco/pushe-flutter/releases

`Version 1.0.0` or lower is not fully compatible with the AndroidX artifacts since Flutter does not touch plugin's codes and does not migrate them.